# Getting Facebook Auth Token Using FSharp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, f#

I am trying to get the OAuth token from facebook using the following code:

```
let applicationId = "12345"
let applicationSecret = "12345"

let tokenBuilder = new StringBuilder()
tokenBuilder.Append("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token?")
tokenBuilder.Append("client_id=")
tokenBuilder.Append(applicationId)
tokenBuilder.Append("&redirect_uri=")
tokenBuilder.Append("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
tokenBuilder.Append("&client_secret=")
tokenBuilder.Append(applicationSecret)

let tokenUri = tokenBuilder.ToString()
let tokenClient = new WebClient()
let tokenResponse = tokenClient.UploadString(tokenUri,String.Empty)
```

When I run it, I get this:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  There are a bunch of configurations that I can make for the application that I guessed like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wild guess: don't you need to URL encode the redirect URL?

Comment: No luck.  UrlEncoding the responseUri still failed.

Comment: Do you have a working example (even if in some other language/platform), so that we can compare?

Comment: Ugh, that is part of the problem.  There is a Facebook.NET SDK but it assumes a WinPhone/Win8/Metro app and the Win10 update is a Universal app.  I tried both using F# (PCL) without any luck so I am now down to webClient and POSTS.  The primary sdk is here: http://facebooksdk.net/

Comment: @JamieDixon: I believe you should also add to your request the OAuth2 flow grant type setting, like this one: `tokenBuilder.Append("&grant_type=client_credentials")`

Comment: @gene -> I added that and still got a 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but this is how you can get the OAuth2 bearer token using `FacebookClient` from Facebook SDK:

```
// nuget Facebook package
open Facebook
type Credentials() = // There are better ways around to make a POCO, anyways...
    member __.client_id with get() = "...your facebook app id here"
    member __.client_secret with get() = "...your facebook app secret here"
    member __.grant_type with get() = "client_credentials"

let fb = FacebookClient()     
let token = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", Credentials())
```

getting back into `token` something like:

```
seq [[access_token, 239907752864330+s3c5obp-fO7DoVX4pPiN69OdAS4]]
```

Comment: I am getting the token back but when I try and request a resource, I am getting a failure: let client' = FacebookClient(token.access_token)
client'.Get("me")

let pageId = "me"
type FacecbookPost = {title:string; message:string}
let post = {title="Test Title"; message = "Test Message"}
client'.Post(pageId + "/feed", post) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.  Is there a way to renew the token?

Comment: Are you sure the failure cause is the token expiration and not the wrong [OAuth2 flow](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2013/03/10/understanding-oauth2/) for the task?